# No such ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment, rbenv

I am having a really strange problem with my current environment.

I am using rbenv, and I have my global and local version of ruby set to ruby 1.9.3-p448

I can even run:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

My bundle works just fine, but as soon as I run:

```
bundle exec rails server
```

I get:

```
env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
```

I know this is a project specific problem, because I can boot up other rails servers just fine. I am guessing this implies that my project is somehow trying to link my ruby 1.9.3 with ruby1.9.1

Does anyone have any debugging ideas? I feel like I have tried everything. =/

Comment: I have the same problem. I cant solve, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a file in the project, .bundle/config, that said:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
```

I took a look in vender/bundle, and sure enough there were two directories, 1.8.7 and 1.9.1

I'm sure to get my project working with 1.9.3, i would either have to create a new directory there, or remove the bundle path from my .bundle config.

To resolve this, I'm just going to get 1.9.1 installed. O_o

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a `ruby` declaration in your Gemfile, or a `.ruby-version` or `.rbenv-version` file in the project, specifying the Ruby you don't have.

Comment: Nope. My Gemfile.lock has no reference to a specific ruby, and my .ruby-version file says 1.9.3-p448

Comment: `Gemfile.lock` won't have it, `Gemfile` may.  If not, I'd try something like a `find . -type f -exec grep -iH ruby1.9.1 {} \;` to dig around and find it.

Comment: If it was in the Gemfile, I'm pretty sure it would be in the Gemfile.lock. That said, your find command did help, i'll post the full answer separately. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you have it in your current ruby environment, do this:

```
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
bundle install # optionally, include --binstubs
bundle exec rails server
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Still getting the same issue

Comment: Regarding the version issue, 1.9.3 gems are still stored in a 1.9.1 directory, e.g.: `~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/`